# Autocompletion on host objects with web based javascript editor

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor, ace-editor

I am at the beginning of a quest to imbed a javascript editor such as Ace og Atom inside a webpage of mine.
I have looked mostly at Ace until now but I am not picky about the exact implementation.

I want to use an imbedable code editor with an autocomplete feature, but I can't figure out how to make it autocomplete on custom made host objects.

I have a number of classes which should be made available to the javascript upon execution, but I can't figure out how to make Ace (Or atom for that matter) aware of these objects.

I have found several tutorials for Ace such as [Ace autocompletion](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/autocompletion.html)
 but none of them seems to touch on custom classes. Can someone explain to me how I can make the autocomplete feature of Ace aware of my own custom classes? Or if you know how to do the same thing with a similar project, that would be very appreciated too.